# Can't add small comments to questions

Tags: support, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

Why can't I add comments to questions?
What do I need in order for this function to be availed to me?

Comment: you need 50 rep, and sometimes it doesn't work in google-chrome

Comment: Haha how cool is that.. didn't know Stackoverflow meta existed :D

Comment: It also mentions using meta.stackoverflow.com in the faq. Worth a read before you start out using the site.

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't add a comment because you haven't reached the necessary reputation level.

Here's an explanation from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

### On Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User

> 50     - Leave comments†
>
> † you can always comment on your
>   questions and answers, and any answers
>   to questions you've asked, even with 1
>   rep.

This means that, **once you've reached 50 reputation, you will be able to comment on any question or answer**. However, "you can always comment on your own questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked" with 1 rep.

---

### On Meta

On Meta, the reputation requirement is different, because of the genre of the site.

So, **you can comment on ANYTHING with 1 rep, but this only applies to Meta.**

---

By the way, just for clarification:

This SO site is called Meta, it's for discussion about Stack Overflow.

If you don't fully understand the concept of reputation, here's an explanation from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> **What is reputation?**
>
> Reputation is completely optional.
>   Normal use of Stack Overflow — that
>   is, asking and answering questions —
>   does not require any reputation
>   whatsoever.
>
> Remember, Stack Overflow is run by
>   you! If you want to help us run the
>   site, you'll need reputation first.
>   Reputation is a (very) rough
>   measurement of how much the Stack
>   Overflow community trusts you.
>   Reputation is never given, it is
>   earned by convincing other Stack
>   Overflow users that you know what
>   you're talking about.
>
> Here's how it works: if you post a
>   good question or helpful answer, it
>   will be voted up by your peers: you
>   gain 10 reputation points. If you post
>   something that's off topic or
>   incorrect, it will be voted down: you
>   lose 2 reputation points. You can earn
>   up to 200 reputation per day, but no
>   more. (Note that votes for any posts
>   marked "community wiki" do not
>   generate reputation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) - check out the list of reputation benefits.