# Is my Google login responsible for me being able to comment on only my own answers?

Tags: bug, comments, google-openid

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can’t comment on other posts, able to comment on own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32352/cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own)
>   [Can’t add small comments to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/cant-add-small-comments-to-questions)
>   [How to comment previous answers in SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30657/how-to-comment-previous-answers-in-so)

I am trying to comment on questions, but the button **add comment** only appears on my own answers. Is this because I use Google to log in?

Comment: Your reputation is not high enough, see the faq

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32352/cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33419/cant-add-small-comments-to-questions-closed
and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30657/how-to-comment-previous-answers-in-so

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough reputation yet, that's why. See the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> 50  Leave comments†

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  This is, of course, a meta-question.